# how to give print(dot matrix printer) in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, printing

In my project i have to print a form, like name, age etc. Its all printed in print paper, i just have to place name , age according to paper. currently i am using a asp.net page to serve my purpose.where i have put labels with position = absolute. when i click on print i am calling that page , in onload event i am putting label values based on previous page content.

it is simple. so is there any better way to print in dotmatrix printer or not? please suggest.

Now prnting works fine, but problem is when i click on print button i am opening that page like popup window and invoke print there. but i want that pop up window to closed after i click print or cancel button. please help me.

my code is like this:

This BtnPrint is in my main page. Main page contains inputs like name, age and etc.
In PrtPage i have placed labels according to space given for printing.So i am loding main page values in onload event of PrtPage.aspx.

protected void BtnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{

    Response.Write("<script>");
    Response.Write("window.open('PrtPage.aspx','_blank')");
    Response.Write("</script>");
}
```

in page load of PrtPage:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{

     Response.Write("<script>");
     Response.Write("window.print()");
     //Response.Write("window.close()");
     Response.Write("<script>");
}
```

but whenever i click on print button it asks ' u want to close window?', so please help me in this. i want to close after i click on print or cancel in print setup window.

or suggest me if there is any good method for printing in dotmatrix..
Thanks in advance.

Sam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a single page instead of opening a pop window. In the below blog post you can see a example usage. Two div tags with printable and non printable content and the div tag with the printable content is hidden. Then you can use Jquery to print content inside a DIV.

http://itzonesl.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-to-print-content-inside-div-tag.html

**Update:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server" >
<title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.printElement.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function printpage() {
        $("#lblName").html($("#TextBox1").val());
        $("#lblSchool").html($("#TextBox2").val());
        $("#printable").printElement();
    }

</script>
<style type="text/css">
#printable { display: none; }
@media print
 {
     #nonprintable { display: none; }
     #printable { display: block; }
 }

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div id="nonprintable">

        <table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="School"></asp:Label>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

 </div>
     <div id="printable">
 <table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="School"></asp:Label>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSchool" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
 </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Print" 
        OnClientClick="printpage();" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**With MasterPage:**

**MasterPage.aspx**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                    My ASP.NET Application
                </h1>
            </div>
              <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**ContentPage.aspx**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.printElement.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function printpage() {
        $("#MainContent_lblName").html($("#MainContent_TextBox1").val());
        $("#MainContent_lblSchool").html($("#MainContent_TextBox2").val());
        $("#printable").printElement();
    }

</script>
<style type="text/css">
#printable { display: none; }
@media print
 {
     #nonprintable { display: none; }
     #printable { display: block; }
 }

</style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
     <div id="nonprintable">

        <table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="School"></asp:Label>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

 </div>
     <div id="printable">
 <table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="School"></asp:Label>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSchool" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
 </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Print" 
        OnClientClick="printpage();" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion chamara, but i think this helps if content is static. but i want dynamic content. so i am using single page and loading contents to it from previous page. also i have put positions or all labels. i can try put those labels in div tag will it work? i can load contents to in onclick of print button later can write jquery , but will this work in asp page?? or only for html page? i mean can it parse <label> tag and all?? will it serve my purpose??

Comment: @SamSimon see whether my update helps you. Remember to include jquery.printElement.js downloaded from the given URL in the blog post

Comment: Thanks you very much for your code. i will try it and let you know :-)

Comment: hi chamara..your code is perfect..but problem is i am using master page. my main page is inside content placeholder..i dont know how to put style inside content. its giving js runtime error..please share example with master page..

Comment: once again..thanks alot :-) working fine with my master page also..Thank you :-)

Comment: one problem now. now i have 2 button. 1 to print patient details and 1 to print bill.. how to do this please?? please suggest me..can i add another div?? will it work?? also i hav to put values befor i print bill..so please help me .....

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting those is that asp.net's scope is limited to the browser window. If the browser is set to ask the user whether they want to close the page when you try to auto-close it (which most appear to be) there's no way of blocking it from the browser.

Same thing with the print, you can't automatically print, because the browser won't let you.

Comment: Thanks Haedrian for your reply.

Comment: So you mean to say there is no other way to close window?? i have to manualy close after i give print??

Comment: Window.Close() is how you close a window. Apparently you could try to cheat: http://thejeshgn.com/2007/10/10/how-to-close-main-browser-window-with-out-getting-warning-message/

But I don't know if that works.

Comment: oh ok..but in my code before printing itself it asks to close window..not after printing. i want to print first and then close that pop up widow.

Comment: or tell me how can i  call that javascript print function inside c# code..so that i can change values of labels and then call print..please help